Prove equivalence of sums with Gamma functions
Consider the following sum:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{a-1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(1+n)^2}\frac{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(c+1)}{\Gamma(-b-c+n)\Gamma(a-n)\Gamma(b-n+1)\Gamma(c-n+1)},
$$
where $a,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Experimentally, I have noticed that this is equal to:
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(a-b-c-1)}\sum_{n=0}^{a-1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(1+n)^2} \binom{a-1}{n}\frac{\Gamma(b+n+1)\Gamma(c+n+1)}{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(c+1)}.
$$
However, I cannot find the correct identities to prove this formally. Is there any straightforward relation one can use for this?

Re-writing the notation slightly we seek to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2}
\frac{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(c+1)}
{\Gamma(-b-c+k) (n-k)! \Gamma(b-k+1) \Gamma(c-k+1)}$$
is equal to
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-b-c)} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2}
{n\choose k} \frac{\Gamma(b+k+1)\Gamma(c+k+1)}
{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(c+1)}.$$
Simplifying the second one,
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-b-c)} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k
{n\choose k} {b+k\choose k} {c+k\choose k}.$$
Simplifying the first one,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(n-k)! \Gamma(-b-c+k)}
(-1)^k {b\choose k} {c\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\Gamma(-b-c+n)}
{-b-c+n-1\choose n-k}
(-1)^k {b\choose k} {c\choose k}.$$
We have reduced to the following claim:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k
{n\choose k} {b+k\choose k} {c+k\choose k}
= \sum_{k=0}^n
{-b-c+n-1\choose n-k}
(-1)^k {b\choose k} {c\choose k}.$$
Here it will suffice to prove it for $c=-b-1$ integers as
both sides are polynomials in $b,c$ and we have equality when two
polynomials agree on an infinite number of values.
We have for the LHS
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k
{n\choose k} {b+k\choose k} {-b-1+k\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^n
{n\choose k} {b+k\choose k} {b\choose k}$$
and for the RHS
$$\sum_{k=0}^n
{-b+b+1+n-1\choose n-k}
(-1)^k {b\choose k} {-b-1\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^n
{n\choose k}
{b\choose k} {b+k\choose k}.$$
We have equality which concludes the argument.
